# Is there any way to specify the column name in the custom sort function of an Aurelia Table?

Tags: aurelia

This might be a very specific way to use aurelia-table, but I would like to know if there is any way to access the key you define in the `aut-sort` parameters in the `custom.bind` function.

Instead of populating the table using a static array for the `data` I'm loading in a JSON array and dynamically creating the table based on what's in the JSON so I can't use `aut-sort` by pointing to the array list value.

If I could only access a key value based on the column I click to sort then I would be able to leverage the custom sort to my needs.

I have already tried defining a global string and attaching an update to that string using a `change.delegate` on the Aurelia Table headers, but the `change.delegate` fires *after* the `custom.bind` sort and the `custom.bind` function is scoped to the Aurelia Table-only anyway.

```
<table aurelia-table="data.bind: data; display-data.bind: $resultsData; current-page.bind: currentPage; page-size.bind: pageSize; total-items.bind: totalItems; api.bind: tableApi;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th repeat.for="[k,v] of responseFields" aut-sort="custom.bind: someSort">${v.displayName}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr repeat.for="result of $resultsData">
                    <td repeat.for="[k,v] of responseFields">
                        ${result[k]}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The `Map` just allows me to set the headers dynamically.

And here is the sort function:

```
someSort(a, b, sortOrder) {
    let sortColumnName = this.sortColumnName;
    let code1 = this.data[this.data.indexOf(a)][sortColumnName];
    let code2 = this.data[this.data.indexOf(b)][sortColumnName];

    if (code1 === code2) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (code1 > code2) {
        return 1 * sortOrder;
    }
    return -1 * sortOrder;
}
```

I would like to be able to define a `sortColumnName` but I currently cannot unless I hard-code it, but I need it to be dynamic.

Comment: be sure to upvote and accept answers if they help you

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to custom order:

```js
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-fetch-client";

export class Example {
    users = [];

    bind(){
        let client = new HttpClient();

        return client.fetch('data.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(users => this.users = users);
    }

    nameLength(row) {
        return row.name.length;
    }

    dateSort(a, b, sortOrder) {
        let date1 = new Date(a.registered);
        let date2 = new Date(b.registered);

        if (date1 === date2) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (date1 > date2) {
            return 1 * sortOrder;
        }

        return -1 * sortOrder;
    }
}
```

```css
 .a ut-sort:before{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    width: 1.28571429em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.aut-sortable:before{
    content: "\f0dc";
}

.aut-asc:before{
    content: "\f160";
}

.aut-desc:before{
    content: "\f161";
}
```

```html
<template>
    <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="data.bind: users; display-data.bind: $displayData">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th aut-sort="key.bind: nameLength">Name</th>
            <th aut-sort="key: age; default: desc">Age</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th aut-sort="custom.bind: dateSort">Registered</th>
            <th aut-sort="key: isActive">Active</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr repeat.for="user of $displayData">
            <td>${user.name}</td>
            <td>${user.age}</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:${user.email}">${user.email}</a></td>
            <td>${user.registered}</td>
            <td>${user.isActive}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by using a `click.capture` that calls a function with the index (`click.delegate` didn't work since that was fired after the `custom.bind`) of the header.

```
<tr class="table-header">
<th repeat.for="item of tableData.columns" click.capture="sort($index)" aut-sort="custom.bind: sortList">
   ${item}
   <div class="arrow"></div>
</th>
```

sort() just sets a private variable

```
private sortIndex = 0;
public sort(index) {
this.sortIndex = index;
}
```

and my custom sort looks like this and uses `sortIndex`

```
 public sortList = (a, b, order) => {

//here I use the index of the header to get the right data from the row
const firstCell = a.cells[this.sortIndex].text;
const secondCell = b.cells[this.sortIndex].text;
  if (order === 1) {
    if (firstCell < secondCell) {
    return -1;
    }
    if (firstCell > secondCell) {
    return 1;
    }
  }
  if (order === -1) {
    if (firstCell < secondCell) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (firstCell > secondCell) {
      return -1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```